# printing int in c by %s in printf

Tags: c, string

[image: Compiled in Borland C++ compiler]

> The compiler doesn't mark it as any error.

- I know that it's wrong,
- but I want to know why it's showing the name of the company.

  1. And it doesn't show this message if I type any value less than 4,
  2. it gives different outputs for different such values, try some
     values like 50, 100,etc.

  Why it's showing such strange outputs.

### Here is the program.

```
void main()
{

  int a=6;

  printf("%s",a);

}
```

Comment: Why did you use s tag?

Comment: It's UB. Don't try to understand it. By definition, it can do anything, including working as expected.

Comment: if you do not ignore warnings then you can easily see that it is not right.

Comment: [on a lighter note] `printing int in c by %s in printf`--- shoot at your foot with a shotgun, you'll get the same effect as the previous. :-)

Comment: @Priyal Kumar, Can you please share your output of above code?

Comment: Please no unreadable screencopys. Post your source code and your output in text form.

Comment: there is not even any warning by the compiler :)

Comment: no, with %c it's printing character instead

Comment: Code: void main()
{

  int a=6;

  printf("%s",a);

}                                                                                                                   /*OUTPUT:- Borland C++ - Copyright 1991 Borland Inc */

Comment: there are only two correct (and one optional) way to declare the main function.  All versions have a 'int' return type.   for your program, suggest using: 'int main( void )'   Then, at the end of the program insert the statement: 'return 0;'

Comment: When compiling, enable all warnings, then fix the warnings. Use a modern compiler.   for the posted code, the following warning is output ""warning: format "%s" expects argument of type 'char *' but argument 2 has type 'int' {-Wformat=]"

Comment: this: 'Borland C++ - Copyright 1991 Borland Inc' is what Borland compiler places at address 6 in the executable file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong specifier for `int` data type. Its undefined behavior. Any thing could happen.

[**Undefined Behavior:**](http://c-faq.com/ansi/undef.html)

> Anything at all can happen; the Standard imposes no requirements. The program may fail to compile, or it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.

Answer (score 4):

Your program behaviour is *undefined* since `%s` is not a valid format specifier for an `int`.

Exactly why it gives you the values it does is down to conjecture. The compiler also reserves the right to eat your cat. And your dog given that `void main()` is not compliant with later C standards.

C intentionally does not guard against your doing this as that would compromise the performance of the language. It's difficult (although not impossible as C is statically typed) for a compiler to warn you of this.

Comment: It's actually extremely common to check `printf` and `scanf` formats against the actual parameters. But Borland is so ancient that it is unlikely that it will check anything.

Answer (score 3):

It shows you not name of the company. Compiler treats `6` as pointer and prints character data from that address until it finds escape sequence `\0`
If you compile this code with different compiler, you will most likely get different results, thats why it is called undefined behavior, as it been rightfully pointed in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should really start to use the minimum standard.
There are a lot of code missing in here and of course you are using an invalid format specifier.
You started with an `int` but you try to print it as a String (%d vs %s)
Also your Main Function it's not ok and the return type is missing too.
This is what you need:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int a=6;

    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```